# Existance of inverse of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I was studying abstract inverse source problem of an abstract heat equation in approach of semi group theory. There I am unable to find the reason of existence of inverse of an operator that i have described below.

> Let $X$ be a Banach space  $\lbrace {T(t)}\rbrace _{t\geq 0}$ be a $C_0$ semi group of contraction of bounded linear operator on $X$ generated by a dissipative operator $A:D(A)\rightarrow X $ , where $D(A)\subset X$ and dense in $X$ . Let $t_0$ is a fixed positive real number. Then $(T(t_0)-I)^{-1}$   exists.

How do i prove the existence? I tried as follows.

As ${T(t)}$ is a $C_0$ semi group of contraction, $||T(t)||\leq \exp(wt)$ for some $w\geq {0}$.
Then $||T(t_0)x-x||\leq |\exp(wt_0)-1|*||x||$ for all $x$ in $ X$. Now if I can able to prove that range of $(T(t_0)-I) $  is $X$, then the operator $(T(t_0)-I)$ is invertible.

Comment: What if you take $A=0$? Do you still find $(T(t_{0})-I)$ to be invertible?

Comment: I am not taking about A=0.Assume that A not equals to zero.

Comment: @AjoyJana: What if $X=Y\oplus Z$ and $A(y,z)=(0,-z)$?

Comment: @AjoyJana Sure that you want to prove the existence of $(T(t_0)-I)^{-1}$? In this framework, usually the existence of $(A-I)^{-1}$ is considered.

Comment: @ saz .. You are right but how can i use the relation you have mention to get my desire result?

Comment: @ Jonas meyer . I did not get your answer.

Comment: @AjoyJana: I was pointing out another basic (type of) counterexample to the claim you ask to prove, such that $A$ need not be zero for the same problem T.A.E. pointed out to occur.  Take $Y$ and $Z$ to be any nonzero Banach spaces you please to make the example more concrete.  But based on saz's comment and your reply, perhaps you have asked the wrong question.  I find it unclear.  [When you put a space between the @ symbol and the username, it does not work to give notification.  I just happened to check back here.]

Comment: @AjoyJana can you provide the reference in which you found this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AjoyJana any answer?